# Making random polygons using python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, polygon

I am a very biginner, and making a code to make a random polygon by python.
I cannot find any error in the code but I cannot print all vertices but only print a pair of x, y coordinate of one vertice. 
Could someone let me know? I think map(tuple, verts) is something problometic.

Thank you very much.

```
import math, random
def generatePolygon( ctrX, ctrY, aveRadius, irregularity, spikeyness, numVerts ) :

    irregularity = clip( irregularity, 0,1 ) * 2*math.pi / numVerts
    spikeyness = clip( spikeyness, 0,1 ) * aveRadius

    # generate n angle steps
    angleSteps = []
    lower = (2*math.pi / numVerts) - irregularity
    upper = (2*math.pi / numVerts) + irregularity
    sum = 0
    for i in range(numVerts) :
        tmp = random.uniform(lower, upper)
        angleSteps.append( tmp )
        sum = sum + tmp

    # normalize the steps so that point 0 and point n+1 are the same
    k = sum / (2*math.pi)
    for i in range(numVerts) :
        angleSteps[i] = angleSteps[i] / k

    # now generate the points
    points = []
    angle = random.uniform(0, 2*math.pi)
    for i in range(numVerts) :
        r_i = clip( random.gauss(aveRadius, spikeyness), 0, 2*aveRadius )
        x = ctrX + r_i*math.cos(angle)
        y = ctrY + r_i*math.sin(angle)
        points.append(( int(x),int(y) ))
        angle = angle + angleSteps[i]

        return points

def clip(x, min, max) :
    if( min > max ) :  return x    
    elif( x < min ) :  return min
    elif( x > max ) :  return max
    else :             return x


verts = generatePolygon( ctrX=250, ctrY=250, aveRadius=100, irregularity=0, spikeyness=0, numVerts=16 )

tupVerts = list(map(tuple,verts))

print(tupVerts)
```

Comment: The problem is your `return` statement that is indented one too many times in `generatePolygone`.

Comment: Interesting code. There's no point doing `list(map(tuple,verts))`: `verts` is already a list of tuples. BTW, you shouldn't use `sum`, `min` or `max` as variable names because that shadows the built-in functions of the same names. (I suggest using `total`, `lo` and `hi` instead). Also, the usual Python convention is to use snake_case for simple variable names, not camelCase, please see [PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You returned too soon from your function - after calculating one point. Here's the problem:

```
for i in range(numVerts) :
    r_i = clip( random.gauss(aveRadius, spikeyness), 0, 2*aveRadius )
    x = ctrX + r_i*math.cos(angle)
    y = ctrY + r_i*math.sin(angle)
    points.append(( int(x),int(y) ))
    angle = angle + angleSteps[i]

    return points # <--- here

for i in range(numVerts) :
    r_i = clip( random.gauss(aveRadius, spikeyness), 0, 2*aveRadius )
    x = ctrX + r_i*math.cos(angle)
    y = ctrY + r_i*math.sin(angle)
    points.append(( int(x),int(y) ))
    angle = angle + angleSteps[i]

return points # <--- Should look like this
```